# How to compile a C program using libgpio(d) for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, gpio, libgpiod

I've got an RPi 5, and I need to do some GPIO programming. I have read that all (most anyway) of the GPIO libraries used on previous models of RPi, and in earlier versions of the Raspbian OS - are now deprecated. I'm told the GPIO library that has survived 'the great cull' is called `libgpio` or `libgpiod` (not sure what the difference is).

I saw a [posting on the RPi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=358676#p2153477) in which a sample program in C was said to have compiled & run successfully. However, I cannot get this to work, so I'm posting here to ask for help.

My C programming skills border on non-existent, but I generally manage to get something working if I'm persistent. Here's what I've tried:

```bash
sudo update
sudo apt install gpiod libgpiod-dev libgpiod-doc 

cd blinky_c                      # blinky.c is in blinky_c
gcc -o blinky -libgpiod blinky.c
blinky.c:3:10: fatal error: lgpio.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "lgpio.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

I do not find `lgpio.h` nor `libgpio(d).h` in either `/usr/include/linux` or `/usr/include`.

`blinky.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lgpio.h"

int h, i;

int main(void) {
    h = lgGpiochipOpen(4);
    lgGpioClaimOutput(h, 0, 17, 0);
    while(1)
    {
        lgGpioWrite(h, 17, 0);
        lguSleep(1);
        lgGpioWrite(h, 17, 1);
        lguSleep(1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How do I get the `lgpio.h` header file, and where & how should it be installed? Is it actually the header file I need?

Comment: some guy written lgpio https://github.com/joan2937/lg/tree/master#download--install library != libgpiod

Comment: @KamilCuk: Ach! You're right - `lgpio.h` is the header file for a different library - it's not for the `libgpiod` library!

Comment: Yes, and please consider using `libgpiod` as it's a standard provided by the Linux kernel.

Comment: @0andriy: hmm... *"provided by the linux kernel"*... those guys have been messing around with this library for years without success. Maybe they're onto something now - I guess we'll see.

Comment: I didn't get. `libgpiod` is the official one from the Linux kernel team. You meant it was messed up?

Comment: @0andriy: Some feel it's messed up badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Read* the thread there. People mention lg library.

> How to compile a C program using libgpio(d) for Raspberry Pi?

*If* you would have a program using libgpio, you would properly compiole it.

> How do I get the lgpio.h header file

Install the library that provides it.

> where

Typically, headers from package managers are installed into /usr/include. Manually installed headers are installed at /usr/local/include.

> how should it be installed?

Follow the installation instructions at https://github.com/joan2937/lg/tree/master#download--install .

You may also consider, *instead* of using lg library, rewriting your program to use libgpiod library.

Comment: *"consider, instead of using lg library, rewriting your program to use libgpiod"*. That's good advice, and that's what I **thought** I was doing - using `libgpiod`.  I mis-read the forum post, and fully realized what happened after reading your reply. The actual answer to my Q is, "No - it is not the header file you need, and the source code you selected isn't what you need either."

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the library, the only .h file is `gpiod.h`. This should have been installed to /usr/include/gpiod.h, so you should be able to access it with just

```
#include <gpiod.h>
```

When in doubt, run `whereis file.h` on the terminal and as long as the file is installed properly, you'll find it.

Comment: Thanks - this is a good answer, and could have been. the accepted one if I had not bodged my question. As I explained in another comment above, I **mistakenly** thought the sample code used the `libgpiod` library. It did not - it used a different library. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Using quotes for your include "gpiod.h" will force the compiler to prioritise the search for this file in your local path (where you are compiling your code).
Using <gpiod.h> will force the compiler to look in systems files, or as defined in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (see also ldconfig). APT should have done this for you.
Try using

```
#include <gpiod.h>
```

as Plaisk suggested.

Comment: The difference between using quotes and angle-brackets is more complex than you might think. Check: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/10871073)